# Datagridview scrolling/last row problem (.Net Winforms)

Tags: winforms, datagridview, scroll, repaint

I have a grid with 7 and half rows visible. I have managed to display the last row fully but the half row space after the last row does not repaint and shows whatever was there previously. Even if I drag another window over my form with the grid and then minimize it, the empty space shows content of the minimized window.
I've tried Invalidate() but no luck.

Hope you understand.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem. I tried all sorts of craziness. In the end, what worked, was that I would hide / show the datagridview control after I inserted a row.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Fantastic. I added hide/show on grid scrolling and it works now. Many thanks!!